# Expanding circle endomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

When I was going through Dynamical systems by Brin and Stuck, I came across this question. I am interested in characterising the expansiveness for invertible linear operator through which expansiveness of toral automorphisms are to be tried.

The continuous homomorphisms from $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ are of the form $z \to z^k; k\in \mathbb{Z}$. For all $|k|>1$, they also enjoy the privilege of being expansive which I am trying to prove. A continuous map $f:(X,d) \to (X,d)$ is said to be expansive if there is a constant $c > 0$ such that for all $x \neq y$, there is a $n(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))>c$.

I would like to prove it without using shift maps. One thing is clear that any arc of length $l$ gets mapped to arc of $|k|l$. How to use this fact. Is this expansiveness actually metric dependent? Such a constant is called expansivity constant. Probably I guess only expansivity constant changes with metrics !!!
Any help in this regard is highly grateful.

Comment: Any comments about the problem will be greatly helpful too

Answer (score 1):

A direct proof (without lifting to the universal cover $\mathbb{R}$) can go like this. Since $|z-w| = |z/w - 1|$, it suffices to prove that for $z\ne 1$, the difference $|z^{k^n}-1|$ cannot be always small. Consider $\arg z \in [-\pi,\pi)$ and note that if $|\arg z|<\pi/k$, then $\arg (z^k) = k \arg z$.

So, if $|\arg f^{(n)}(z)|<\pi/k$ for all $n$, then the sequence $|\arg f^{(n)}(z)|$ grows exponentially, which is absurd.

---

Being expansive indeed depends on a metric in general. For example, the map $f(x)=x+1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is not expansive in the standard metric, but is expansive in the metric $d(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|$.

Comment: What is expansivity constant in either case?  Expansivity becomes independent of the metric if the underlying space is compact !!